# What if a program needs an exe on PATH?

Tags: python, path, exe

I am trying to create a program that opens web pages when a user runs it. The problem is that the driver we use to control the browser needs to be added to PATH on the users side.

Is adding to PATH on the users side something that can be achieved with a program/installation wizard?

I'm using Python 3.8

Many thanks

Comment: You can place the driver in the same directory.

Comment: Modifying their PATH variable? Possible, but not recommended as it will be very error-prone. The best thing to do is put the executable somewhere already in a common PATH, such as /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin

Comment: thanks guys. I forgot to mention that the user will have a windows environment.

Comment: Does anyone know the best Windows 10 folder to use so my program will already have access to PATH once it is installed? Thank you